# IPv6 resolving as loopback/private IP

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, bind, ipv6, ipv4

I'm running a web crawler and I received some reports from my datacenter about connections directing to private IPs (like 10.0.0.1). I've implemented a loopback/private ip check to my crawler code and I realized that many domains resolves to following IPv6 addresses.

- 7777:772e:726f:7763:6174:6368:2e63:6f6d
- 7777:772e:726f:7763:726f:6674:2e6f:7267

I'm using my own Bind DNS cache and also when I try to visit these domains on some other computer/network, I can visit them without a problem and all their DNS settings looks okay.

What can be the reason for resolving these domains as private/loopback IPv6 addresses as seen above? What can I do to check any other things related to this issue?

Can it be because of my BIND DNS Cache? Can it be because of misconfigured router at my datacenter?

Thank you very much in advance...

**Solution:** @kasperd helped me a lot on this problem and he found that it was because of an wrong implementation on my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making some incorrect assumptions in your question.

The majority of IPv6 address space is reserved, including the `6000::/3` range which the two addresses you mention belong to.

If any reserved address ever shows up in a AAAA record it indicates an invalid configuration. This can cause connectivity problems, though properly implemented clients will fall back to using one of the other addresses for that domain.

The first obvious reason for an invalid address showing up in a AAAA record is that whoever configured that AAAA record in the first place made a mistake. If you mentioned a domain name, we might be able to tell you whether this is the case.

It is also possible to produce such invalid AAAA records by misconfiguring a caching DNS server. I think Bind has sufficient flexibility to introduce such problems.

A misconfigured router would not in itself be enough to produce such a problem. But many routers have additional features unrelated to routing, so it is in theory possible that your router could have features, which if used incorrectly would produce such invalid records.

If you look closely on the invalid IPv6 addresses, you will see that every octet is within the range of printable ASCII characters (`20` - `7e`). That may provide a hint about where the invalid addresses originated from.

Summary of debugging in chat. The problem was due to a bug in the crawler code:

```
ip = ipaddress.ip_address(hostname)
```

That line would interpret any hostname that happened to be exactly 16 characters long as if it was an IPv6 address. No DNS resolution was performed on the hostname.

Comment: Thank you very much @kasperd :) I don't know much about configuring for IPv6, I set allow-query { localhost; } on BIND and also set listen-on-v6{ any; }.

Do you have any idea about what to set or not? I think I need more specific instructions. :(

Comment: @shehatesme Those settings are not causing the problem. If you could provide a specific example of a domain name that you have a problem with, that might help.

Comment: Lots of domains have problem with it but for example, now these domains returns following IPv6 addresses

www.the-gsba.org - 7777:772e:7468:652d:6773:6261:2e6f:7267
www.the-gsxr.com -7777:772e:7468:652d:6773:7872:2e63:6f6d

More than that, if these means "unresolved/misconfigured", many domains seems to direct our crawlers to internal IP's of our datacenter (Hetzner) and they report us about that. However, also loopback, reserved and private IP's are block on our crawler by code too.

Comment: @shehatesme I get no `AAAA` record for that domain. I now suspect something may be hijacking DNS queries between your Bind cache and the authoritative servers. Does the same happen if you send the queries to a different DNS server such as `8.8.8.8` or `2001:4860:4860::8888`?

Comment: @shehatesme Try these four commands: `dig -t aaaa www.the-gsba.org @8.8.8.8` ; `dig -t aaaa www.the-gsba.org @2001:4860:4860::8888` ; `dig -t aaaa mydnsv6.kasperd.net @8.8.8.8` ; `dig -t aaaa mydnsv6.kasperd.net @2001:4860:4860::8888`

Comment: Here is the results: http://pastebin.com/CfrWCc4j    Also I've added 127.0.0.1 to the end of them (which is my local DNS cache)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33582/discussion-between-kasperd-and-she-hates-me).

Comment: Dammit. I was also seeing the pattern in these strange IPv6 addresses, but I didn't recognize that `7777772e` is just 'www.' in hex!

Comment: @Dubu I recognized pretty much immediately that it was ASCII. From there it was only a short step to figure out that they started with `www.`. The tricky part was figuring out at what point the domain name was assumed to be the binary representation of an IP address.